# Yelp API - Pull all Reviews for a business

Tags: api, yelp

I was reading through the API and I clicked on Business API and found `reviews` as a possible response. The description reads,

`List of up to 1 review snippet for the business`

Does this mean I cannot pull all my reviews for my business onto my website? I could only show 1 snippet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is correct, there is no way to get more reviews from the Yelp API.

You would have to write a web scraper. http://www.jacobward.co.uk/web-scraping-with-php-curl-part-1/

Comment: and they would get mad at you probably because they want traffic.

Answer (score 1):

YELPs EULA forbids web scraping.

Under the Restricts section, subsection 2, item 3, "Use any robot, spider, site search/retrieval application, or other automated device, process or means to access, retrieve, scrape, or index any portion of the Site or any Site Content;"

If you do it be careful.  These websites have gone after folks hard in the past...

EDIT: by do it I am referring to the webscraping that was suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Yelp will ban your IP if you run your web scraper too often